# Fluxible storeListeners event emitter

Tags: reactjs, flux

Is there a way to discover which handler fired the event?

For example, my store:

```
handlers: {
        surahReceived(payload) {
            this._surah = payload.surah;
            this.emitChange();
        },
        ayahsReceived(payload) {
            this.dispatcher.waitFor('AyahStore', function() {
                this._surah.ayahs = this.dispatcher.getStore(AyahStore).getAyahs();
            }.bind(this));
            this.emitChange();
        },
        surahListReceived(payload) {
            this._surahs = payload.surahs;
            this.emitChange();
        }
    }
```

And when the last function fires, my listeners:

```
statics: {
        storeListeners: {
            _onSurahReceived: [SurahStore]
        }
    },
```

I'd like to find out which function fired the event

Comment: If you're asking if you can include additional meta data as part of the change trigger, then No, there isn't. The basic premise of React and Flux is that you shouldn't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this:

You can pass arguments to `emitChange`.

For example:

```
surahListReceived(payload) {
            this._surahs = payload.surahs;
            this.emitChange(1);
        }
```

Then in your view:

```
statics: {
        storeListeners: {
            _onSurahReceived: [SurahStore]
        }
    },
_onSurahReceived: function(e) {
  console.log(e) // Should be 1
}
```